# Buyer to Seller Venmo Direct Transactions Integration

Tags: react-native, transactions, expo, e-commerce, venmo

My company is an college-focused, online e-commerce platform that lets sellers to buy items/services from buyers. It is vital that we use Venmo (Stripe as a hesitant second option) to allow direct transactions between users. Users will add their Venmo details and will be able to transact with one another. The company will take a 5-10% royalty off every transaction.

I could not find a way to do this so far. Has this been successfully done before? Or is this only possible by doing Buyer -> Company -> Seller? I want it to be Buyer -> Seller.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.